# Why does $\frac d{dx}\int_0^xf(t)\ dt=f(x)$ not hold when $f(t)$ contains an $x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$\frac d{dx}\int_0^xf(t)\ dt=f(x)$, but it seems $f(t)$ should not contain an $x$. For example,

$$f(t)=t-x$$

$$\frac d{dx}\int_0^xf(t)\ dt=-x\neq f(x)$$

More complex $f(t)$s with an $x$ also produce such results, but I couldn't figure out why. What is wrong in the following calculation?

$$f(t)=t-x$$

$$g(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\ dt=F(x)-F(0)$$

$$g'(x)=F'(x)-F'(0)=f(x)$$

Comment: $F(0)$ is not constant with respect to $x.$

Comment: If $f$ contains an $x$ it will be written as $f(t,x)$ which is a function of two variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the term of $f(t)$ also contains $x$ either as a further variable or as a parameter, then the derivative $\frac d{dx}$ does no longer just apply to the upper limit of the integral $\int^x_0$ only. Thus the cited theorem no longer applies simply because its proof would go wrong.

--- rk